# Lindström-Gessel-Viennot from properties of the $Alt^k$ functor?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, determinants

Let $A$ be the directed adjacency matrix of an acyclic directed graph, with variables as its nonzero entries (one for each edge). The $(a,b)$ entry of the matrix $(I-A)^{-1}$ is the sum over all paths $a\to b$ of the product of the edge labels.

In the [Lindström-Gessel-Viennot lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindstr%C3%B6m%E2%80%93Gessel%E2%80%93Viennot_lemma) one obtains an interpretation of $Alt^k((I-A)^{-1})$, whose rows and columns are indexed by $k$-tuples of vertices. The $((a_1,\ldots,a_k),(b_1,\ldots,b_k))$ entry is a sum over $k$-tuples of paths from $(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$ to $(b_1,\ldots,b_k)$, of the edges used in the paths, but with the interesting condition that no two paths are allowed to touch at any vertex. (There is also a sign having to do with how the $a$s and $b$s are matched up.)

This is traditionally proven by a sign-reversing involution. Is there a wholly linear-algebraic proof, based on $Alt^k$ being a functor?

Here is something that doesn't work: $(A^n)_{ab}$ computes paths $a\to b$ of length $n$. If we compute entries in $Alt^k(A^n) = (Alt^k A)^n$, they count $k$-tuples of paths where each is of length $n$, and, no two paths are allowed to collide *after the same number of steps*. (E.g the $a_1 \to b_3$ path $(a_1, x, y, z, \ldots, b_3)$ would collide with the $a_2 \to b_5$ path $(a_3,p,q,r,\ldots, b_5)$ if $y=q$, but $y=r$ would be just fine.)

Comment: Very interesting question! As a place to start: the LGV lemma easily gives a proof of the Cauchy-Binet formula. Do you know of a proof of the Cauchy-Binet formula of this kind?

Comment: (Although I suppose that for the Cauchy-Binet application, the relevant digraph is "layered," so that indeed paths can only collide after the same number of steps, which means your caveat does not come into play.)

Comment: (Conversely you can likely break up any "layered" digraph into chunks and apply Cauchy-Binet to connect them, so perhaps my idea for a place to start is actually not so useful for your question.)

Comment: Cauchy-Binet is exactly the statement that $Alt^k(AB) = Alt^k(A)\cdot Alt^k(B)$ where $A$ is $k\times n$ and $B$ is $n\times k$. The matrix $Alt^k(A)$ is a $1\times{n\choose k}$ matrix (or row vector) whereas $Alt^k(B)$ is a column vector, and their product is essentially a dot product.

Comment: Perhaps whenever we have a graph where two paths starting from some source vertices can intersect after a different number of steps, we can always construct an “equivalent” graph via edge subdivisions where intersections only happen after the same number of steps.